Shrink Amazon Linux EC2 xvda instance
I know this has been asked before, but every solution I've tried so far hasn't worked.
I have a 96GB volume with both boot and data on it (yes, I know... it was a mistake not to split them). I've moved all my images to a CDN, and now I'm trying to shrink the drive to reduce costs. I created a clone of an old 8GB Linux drive using cp with the files from my current one, and while it boots, it keeps asking for a different private key/user combination to SSH in.
I tried doing a block copy from a compressed version of the volume to a new 8GB volume, but it did not boot.
An rsync attempt from the main partition to the new drive also didn't boot.
I keep ending up having to reattach the larger volume to the instance and leave that running. Otherwise, it either won't boot, or I can't get into SSH (I suspect the issue might be that the key is based on a combination of the original private key and the volume ID in xvda?).
I could really use some help here instead of the standard "You have to start a new one and reinstall everything" answer.
